# Вопрос на счет апдейта софта

Tags: update

Когда пишется софт самый простой, то куда вписывается код, который отвечает за апдейт этого софта, то есть если вышел апдейт, то софт автоматически обновился на новый. Может быть для этого дело делается .dll файл ? Я хз, поэтому спрашиваю.....

Comment: апдейт - это и есть новый код, либо новый код на место другого

Comment: Куда угодно, где он будет выполнен в нужные моменты.

Comment: а возможно ли как то через другой софт блокировать срабатывания этого кода, который отвечает за апдейт ?

Comment: Блокировать - что имеется в виду? Но в общем случае без фатальных последствий для работы программы - только если это предусмотрено кодом приложения.

Comment: Блокировать - это в моем понимании значит, что я запустил софт, который блочит апдейт, и мой софт не дает сработать коду в другом софте, который отвечает за апдейт того софта

Comment: Обычно обновления добываются из Инета. Достаточно заблокировать приложению доступ к URL проверки либо загрузки обновления... с самим приложением при этом можно ничего не делать.

Comment: Легко. Знакомы с реверс инжинирингом? Удалите инструкции проверки апдейта (или всегда валидным). Блокировка сетевым экраном программы-апдейтера. Выключение вообще сети. Выбирай любой.

Comment: Гут....))))))))))))

Answer (score 1):

Можно сделать через специальный update модуль. Самому себя модулю сложно обновить, может быть конфликт доступа (криво процессы прибьётся). 
Отдельный модуль может прибить основной процесс, обновить все модули и завершится.
Вызов его можно делать из основного модуля при запуске или из планировщика ОС. В планировщика много таких апдейтеров сидит практически для каждой программы и особенно браузеров и мессенджеров.